# LaTeX - Break in math

Tags: math, latex

I would like to be able to break lines in a math environment but in a way that keeps a symbol in front of the formula.

For example, the sum (sigma) followed by a long formula. So it goes out of the page but I would like to keep the formula next to the sigma even if there's a line break.

Here's a snippet so you can better reproduce it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools}

% allows me to increase the font size of math blocks
\usepackage{graphicx} % \scalebox
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{mymath}{%
    \[
        \scalebox{1.3}{$\BODY$}
    \]
}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    \begin{mymath}
        \sum \limits _{\substack{
            yyyyyyy,\\
            zzzzzzzz,\\
            www
        }}
        (
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        ) + (
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        )
    \end{mymath}
\end{document}
```

And here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve.
[image]

So as you can see, I'm trying to keep the second parenthesis next to the sigma but under the first parenthesis.

Comment: Don't use the simple `$` math environment then. The `amsmath` package has many specialized environments for multiline _aligned_ equations. Have you had a look at the amsmath documentation yet?

Comment: Note that there is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/ where it's more easy to get an answer and search for similar questions. For instance: [How can I write multiple lines in a subscript?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/how-can-i-write-multiple-lines-in-a-subscript) suggests using `\substack`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: [don't scale elements that contain text!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text) If you don't like the size of your math block, use an appropriate font size instead.

You can use the `split` environment from `amsmath` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    \[
    \begin{split}
        \sum \limits_{\substack{
            yyyyyyy,\\
            zzzzzzzz,\\
            www
        }}
       & (
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        ) +\\
        &(
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        )
    \end{split}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm.

Comment: @MaxBresil You're welcome!